# how do I turn this into a 'on click' error message?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, error-handling

I've got a user signup form with email and password inputs.

I have the jQuery for the email to validate sorted but on the client side the password is to show an error on clicking submit if the password input is empty.

I've got this working when the page loads

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":input").each(function() {
       if($(this).val() === "")
            $('#password_default_value').show();
    });
});
```

But need to get it so it only checks when the user clicks the #login-submit button

I've tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-submit').click(function() {
    $(":input").each(function() {
       if($(this).val() === "")
            $('#password_default_value').show();
    });
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. I'm guessing my code is badly in error somewhere but I can't see where.

Any pointers?

Comment: @undefined technically not. He just swapped `});` with `}`

Comment: thanks 'undefined' and Fabricio :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some messed up parenthesis, try like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-submit').click(function() {
        $(":input").each(function() {
            if($(this).val() === "") {
                $('#password_default_value').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also if `#login-submit` is a submit button of a form you should return false from your click handler, otherwise the page will navigate away when the user clicks on this submit button and your javascript might never have the time to execute.

Comment: those kinds of mistakes are *much* easier to find when is properly indented!

Comment: @ZachL, yes, you are completely right. Proper indentation always helps. And javascript debugging tools such as FireBug or Chrome Developer Toolbar are a must use.

Comment: thanks Zach, Yeah I need to get _much_ better at that. Any pointers?

Comment: @StuartRobson, yeah, go get FireBug and impose yourself a consisting indentation when writing code.

Comment: you can also check out different javascript "style guides" here's the [jQuery projects JS style guide](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/)